AWS selected Folders Transfer between buckets
Under My AWS Cloud S3 storage account i have around 55000 folders.
We are in process to reduce the size of the storage and to do that we have to move around 40000 folders.
What i need help from you guys is, how do i run the batch file of 40000 folders to move that many from the aws bucket to another bucket?
Thanks in advance.
Until now i have tried to run some scripty which i have find online for aws cli.
Because of error in configuration i am not able to run the command.

What is the AWS CLI error you are experiencing? It would be worthwhile getting that working.

One option is to use the AWS CLI, as you mention. You can use a command like:
aws cli mv --recursive s3://source-bucket/folder s3://destination-bucket/folder/

It performs a Copy, and then it Deletes the source object.
Alternatively, you could Copy objects using S3 Batch Operations - Amazon Simple Storage Service. This involves obtaining a list of objects ('manifest') using Amazon S3 Inventory, and then using that manifest to tell it to copy the objects elsewhere.
Please note that 'folders' do not actually exist in Amazon S3. You either need to move the individual objects, or use a --recursive command to tell it to include objects that are in the same path.
